# How to convert normal date to JSON date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

My question is easy.

There is a lot of information about converting JSON date (Date/00213912321/) to normal date (7/03/14 10:00 am).

**But I need to do the inverse. I have a normal date and I need it in JSON format. How can I achieve that?**

I'm using jQuery so if there is some plugin that I can use, it'll be great.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'JSON date'. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Date())` outputs `2014-03-07T16:29:39.498Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a JSON Date. JSON doesn't support any type for dates.

`00213912321` appears to be epoch time. You can get that from a Date object with the `getTime` method.

Therefore:

```
var date = "Date/" + someDateObject.getTime()  + "/";
```

Comment: This was just what I needed. Sorry, I dind't know the existance of epoch time until today. I thought that Date/1230931819/ was some kind of Json format. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you have a regular date, perhaps the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object can parse it.

```
var dateObj = new Date('7/03/14 10:00 am');
    timestamp = dateObj.getTime();  // timestamp is 1404396000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunatelly I cannot give you both acepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// convert json date into normal date.
function ConvertJsonDateString(jsonDate)
{
    var shortDate = null;

    if (jsonDate)
    {
        var regex = /-?\d+/;
        var matches = regex.exec(jsonDate);
        var dt = new Date(parseInt(matches[0]));
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        const monthNames = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                           ];
        var monthString =  monthNames[month];
        // var monthString = month > 9 ? month: '0' + month;
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var dayString = day > 9 ? day : '0' + day;
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        shortDate = monthString + '-' + dayString + '-' + year;
    }
    return shortDate;
};
```

Ajax Json

```
{ "data": function (r) {
    var date = ConvertJsonDateString(r.Jsondate);
    var Expirydt = date == null ? "" :  date;
    return Expirydt;
    }
},
```